# object BLAS in package linalg cannot be accessed in package org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg

Tags: apache-spark

I want to use some functions provided in the BLAS class, so I imported this class (import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.BLAS)

The problem is when I write, for example,

```
BLAS.axpy(1.0, p1, p2)
```

I get this error:

```
object BLAS in package linalg cannot be accessed in package org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg
```

I'm using the 1.2.0 version of spark !

Does some one have an idea how to solve this problem ?! thanks

Answer (score 0):

`BLAS` is not a public class or API. You can't call it from your app.

Comment: I actually ran into same issue, so how can I issue something like BLAS.axpy?